# Display xml data in a webpage with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to display the data of a xml parsed page which i get from a external source. which i got passing through some parameters like this:-

http://www.somewebsite.com/phpfile.php?vendor_key=xxx&checkin=2012-11-02&checkout=2012-11-05&city_id=5&guests=3

when i pass this parameters i got an xml result. now i want to display that xml data in a designer way on my webpage. so how can i do so. i am new to xml so dont know what this technology called if any body can tell me what this called so that can also help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to make HTTP request. Then after you can use `DOM` or `SimpleXML` to parse the response (XML) of requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

If u have already XMl then try

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

A full example

```
<?php 
 $curl = curl_init();        
 curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');   
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
 $result = curl_exec ($curl);   

 if ($result === false) {
      die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));   
 }
   curl_close ($curl);    

//we can at this point echo the XML if you want
 //echo $result;

 //parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

   if ($xml === false) {
      die('Error parsing XML');   
   }

   //now we can loop through the xml structure
   foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
       print $item->title;   
   }
```

Comment: i am getting the xml from an outer source. so how can i put the xml here. do i put the url where i am passing parameter here

    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');

Comment: i have the url where i have to pass parameter like this:- 


    http://www.somewebsite.com/feeds/phpfile.php?vendor_key=xxx&checkin=2012-11-02&checkout=2012-11-05&city_id=5&guests=3

and this return me a webpage with xml code. now i am asking that where i have to put this url in your code?

Comment: In place of http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories. This is the url of the page from where u want to get the feeds